# PyQt - Main hangs on QThread

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qthread

I have a Python QT application that connects to a CG server (CasparCG). The QT application triggers a QThread which listens for hotkeys using the module *pynput* - and sends a command to CasparCG to playback different video files for each of the keys pressed.

In the Main GUI, I can assign video files to a list of hotkeys, and I trigger the HotKey listening thread from a submenu item.

```
self.actionStart_Hotkeys = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
self.menuCasparCG.addAction(self.actionStart_Hotkeys)    
self.actionStart_Hotkeys.triggered.connect(self.StartHotkeys)
```

The Main app and Ui_Window code is very long and has no problems - it functions like it should. Videos also playback as I would expect when the HotKeys are activated by pressing keys, but the Main window of the application freezes after a few video files are played - and I'm not sure why the main GUI is not responding to input after the HotKey thread is started.

The code up until now looks like this..

```
from pynput import keyboard

class HotKeys(QThread):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        QThread.__init__(self, parent)
        self.COMBINATIONS = [
            {keyboard.KeyCode(char='0')},
            {keyboard.KeyCode(char='1')},
            {keyboard.KeyCode(char='2')},
            {keyboard.KeyCode(char='3')},  
            ]

        self.caspar = None
        self.current = set()
        self.Connect()
        self.Listen()

    def exit(self, i):
        if not self.caspar == None:
            self.caspar.close
        sys.exit(i)

    def Connect(self):
        try:
            self.caspar = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            self.caspar.connect(("127.0.0.1", 5250))
            print("Connected to caspar")

        except socket.error:
            print("CasparCG not running, or incorrect settings.xml")
            self.exit(0)

    def execute(self, k=None): # k is videofile 
        movie = bytes("PLAY 1-20 {} \r\n".format(k), 'utf8')
        self.caspar.send(movie)

    def on_press(self, key):
        if any([key in COMBO for COMBO in self.COMBINATIONS]):
             self.current.add(key)
            if any(all(k in self.current for k in COMBO) for COMBO in self.COMBINATIONS):
                self.execute(key)

    def on_release(self, key):
        if any([key in COMBO for COMBO in self.COMBINATIONS]):
            self.current.remove(key)

    def Listen(self):
        with keyboard.Listener(on_press=self.on_press, on_release=self.on_release) as listener:
            listener.join()
```

I trigger this Hotkey QThread in the Main class of the application like this...

```
class Main(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self) # from Ui_MainWindow class       

    def StartHotkeys(self):
        hotkey_thread = HotKeys(self)
        hotkey_thread.start()
```

and the application like this...

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv) 
    gui = Main()
    gui.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

So why does Main freeze?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`QThread` is not a thread, it is a thread handler, if you want to execute a task in another thread you must do it in the `run()` method, that method is the only part that is executed in the other thread. In your case the `Listen()` task is blocking and you call it in the constructor, and the `QThread` constructor runs in the GUI thread, that's why your GUI freezes. The solution is to move Connect and Listen to the `run()` method:

```
class HotKeys(QThread):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QThread.__init__(self, parent)
        self.COMBINATIONS = [
            {keyboard.KeyCode(char='0')},
            {keyboard.KeyCode(char='1')},
            {keyboard.KeyCode(char='2')},
            {keyboard.KeyCode(char='3')},  
            ]

        self.caspar = None
        self.current = set()

    def run(self):
        self.Connect()
        self.Listen()

    def exit(self, i):
        if self.caspar:
            self.caspar.close()
        sys.exit(i)

    def Connect(self):
        try:
            self.caspar = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            self.caspar.connect(("127.0.0.1", 10000))
            print("Connected to caspar")

        except socket.error:
            print("CasparCG not running, or incorrect settings.xml")
            self.exit(0)

    def execute(self, k=None): # k is videofile 
        if self.caspar:
            movie = bytes("PLAY 1-20 {} \r\n".format(k), 'utf8')
            self.caspar.send(movie)

    def on_press(self, key):
        if any([key in COMBO for COMBO in self.COMBINATIONS]):
            self.current.add(key)
            if any(all(k in self.current for k in COMBO) for COMBO in self.COMBINATIONS):
                self.execute(key)

    def on_release(self, key):
        if any([key in COMBO for COMBO in self.COMBINATIONS]):
            self.current.remove(key)

    def Listen(self):
        with keyboard.Listener(on_press=self.on_press, on_release=self.on_release) as listener:
            listener.join()
```

Comment: Very clear and simple answer thankyou - I understand more now the handler class, and the actual running thread - I was confusing it with the code that runs on init.